# "Can't find file" error when calling UploadFiles

Tags: c#, ftp, upload, fluentftp

I'm having an issue with the `UploadFiles` method of the FluentFTP library. This is my code:

```
var count = _client.UploadFiles(filesPaths, remotePath, true, true);
foreach(var path in filesPaths)
{
    AddLog(string.Format("Uploaded File: {0}", path));
}
```

And after execute `UploadFiles` it throws an exception saying **Can't find file**. I discovered when I use `remotePath = "/uploads"` I have this issue, but when I set remotePath to `"/"`, the method uploads files without problems. I checked user permissions and he can do everything.

I don't know what could be the problem. I read the source code in GitHub and I didn't find anything weird.

Is it a bug of FluentFTP? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Future readers should see the cross-post on the library's issue tracker, at https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/issues/70. The underlying cause was a permissions issue on the FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder **/uploads** is not created, you will get that exception.

Option 1: Create the folder **uploads** manually and try again

Option 2: Use

> DirectoryExists() - Check if a directory exists on the server.
>
> CreateDirectory() - Creates a directory on the server. If the parent
> directories do not exist they are also created.